# ftok pathname vs. filename

Tags: c, parameters, pathname, ftok

```
key_t ftok(const char *pathname, int proj_id);
```

What if I use a filename for the first parameter instead of pathname?
For example, my program is in the following directory
`/afs/edu/id/group/a/ftok_test.c`

In this case, if I use

```
int key = ftok(/afs/edu/id/group/a/ftok_test.c, 1);
int key = ftok(/afs/edu/id/group/a, 1);
```

What is the difference these two?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/ftok.html) says:

> The application shall ensure that the path argument is the pathname of
>   an existing file that the process is able to stat().

So your second example is ill-formed, because it refers to a directory.